# How to mySQL ORDER BY in this case

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have this `table` and trying to show data `ORDER BY` but based on multiple column.

**Table:**

```
_______________________________________________
id | title | dis | cityid | dist | queue | date
_______________________________________________
1  |  abc  | 1   |  1     |  0   |  1    | 2017
2  |  cde  | 1   |  1     |  0   |  1    | 2017
3  |  efg  | 1   |  1     |  0   |  1    | 2017
4  |  ghi  | 1   |  1     |  0   |  1    | 2017
5  |title1 | 1   |  1     |  1   |  1    | 2017
6  | title2| 2   |  1     |  2   |  2    | 2017
7  | abc   | 2   |  1     |  0   |  2    | 2017
8  | cde   | 2   |  1     |  0   |  2    | 2017
9  | efg   | 2   |  1     |  0   |  2    | 2017
```

**Goal:**

```
titl1
abc
cde
efg
ghi
titl12
abc
cde
efg
```

**Query:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM district ORDER BY title ASC, queue ASC";
```

Also i tried:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM district ORDER BY title ASC, dist ASC";
```

But none of these works, any suggestion?
Also i have free ability to add/remove column or change data (like dist, queue) to implement this.

Those data that have dis = 1 are sub group of title 1, and those have dis = 2 are sub group of title 2, title1 and 2 are hading.

For first query result is:

```
    abc
    cde
    efg
    ghi
    titl1
    titl12
    abc
    cde
    efg
```

Comment: _"But none of these works"_ - How didn't it work? What happened? Errors? Wrong sorting? If the later, tried any other ways/combinations?

Comment: why have all your rows the same id? - you could `order by queue, title desc` - for your demodata this would lead to the desired outcome BUT nothing in this ordering does anything with your dists - im still not sure how you contrieved your "wanted" order

Comment: oh sorry @PatrickArtner i forget to change these, i just wrote for example, this is not real data

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It is clear, isn't it? data not showing that i want. i going to add current result to question

Comment: `ORDER BY dis ASC, dist DESC, title ASC`?

Comment: No, _"not working"_ is _far_ from a clear description.

Comment: sorry if it was unclear @MagnusEriksson

Comment: No worries, you've updated the question which is the important thing. Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: What's the point of including 9 identical `ids`? How does that help us?

Comment: @Strawberry i told in comments, i wrote this example here, this is not real data, and i forget to change `ids` , anyway problem already solved.

Comment: looking at table dataset provided - it seem you have not proper formatted strings there. first `___abc` and second `__abc` have different number of leading spaces I guess. to confirm just try `ORDER BY TRIM(title) ASC, dist ASC"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you want to sort by the main groups `dis` and show the lowest first:

```
ORDER BY dis ASC
```

Then, within that sorting, you want to sort all with the same `dis` to get the headers (where `dist` isn't zero) first:

```
ORDER BY dis ASC, dist DESC
```

And lastly, you want the rest to come in alphabetic order:

```
ORDER BY dis ASC, dist DESC, title ASC
```

Comment: Thanks. can't +1, system says, need 15 rep to vote up.